# Mapping column values

Tags: r, replace, dictionary, dataframe, transform

I would like to transform the values of a given column using some mapping function. Example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = sample(1:20, 10))
df
   A  B
1  1 17
2  2  5
3  3  3
4  4 11
5  5 19
6  1 16
7  2  4
8  3  7
9  4  6
10 5  9
```

My goal is to map all elements of column A as following:

```
1 -> "tt"
2 -> "ff"
3 -> "ss"
4 -> "fs"
5 -> "sf"
```

I have written the following:

```
mappingList <- c("tt", "ff", "ss", "fs", "sf")
df$A <- unlist(lapply(df$A, function(x){replace(x, x>0, mappingList[x])}))
df
  A  B
1  tt 17
2  ff  5
3  ss  3
4  fs 11
5  sf 19
6  tt 16
7  ff  4
8  ss  7
9  fs  6
10 sf  9
```

The code as above worked fine.

Now let's assume another dataframe where column A is not made of integers 1,2,3,4,5 but rather any other 'generic' items, say:

```
df <- data.frame(A = paste("str",1:5,sep=""), B = sample(1:20, 10))
```

or

```
df <- data.frame(A = seq(5, 25, by=5), B = sample(1:20, 10))
```

Question: How would you write the mapping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at `factor`?

```
df$A_2 <- factor(df$A, levels = 1:5, labels = c("tt", "ff", "ss", "fs", "sf"))
df
#    A  B A_2
# 1  1 17  tt
# 2  2  5  ff
# 3  3  3  ss
# 4  4 11  fs
# 5  5 19  sf
# 6  1 16  tt
# 7  2  4  ff
# 8  3  7  ss
# 9  4  6  fs
# 10 5  9  sf
```

Basically, your `levels` argument should have the original values to match, and your `labels` argument should have the replacement values.

---

You could also create a look-up table with a named vector.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = paste("str",1:5,sep=""), B = sample(1:20, 10))

NamedVec <- setNames(paste("str",1:5,sep=""), c("tt", "ff", "ss", "fs", "sf"))
NamedVec
#     tt     ff     ss     fs     sf
# "str1" "str2" "str3" "str4" "str5" 
NamedVec[df$A]
#     tt     ff     ss     fs     sf     tt     ff     ss     fs     sf 
# "str1" "str2" "str3" "str4" "str5" "str1" "str2" "str3" "str4" "str5" 
names(NamedVec[df$A])
#  [1] "tt" "ff" "ss" "fs" "sf" "tt" "ff" "ss" "fs" "sf"
```

Comment: Specifically `df$A <- factor(df$A, levels=c("str1","str2","str3","str4","str5"), labels=c("tt", "ff", "ss", "fs", "sf"))` or `df$A <- factor(df$A, levels=c(5,10,15,20,25), labels=c("tt", "ff", "ss", "fs", "sf"))`

Comment: Great, I like the look up table idea using the named vector. Thx a lot Ananda !

Comment: @Riad, relevant reading from SO user [@PaulHiemstra](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1033808/paul-hiemstra): http://www.numbertheory.nl/2014/01/25/vectorisation-is-your-best-friend-replacing-many-elements-in-a-character-vector/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mappingList[df$A]
#[1] "tt" "ff" "ss" "fs" "sf" "tt" "ff" "ss" "fs" "sf"
```

For the two other datasets:

```
df1 <-  data.frame(A = paste("str",1:5,sep=""), B = sample(1:20, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(A = seq(5, 25, by=5), B = sample(1:20, 10))

mappingList[as.numeric(df1$A)]
#[1] "tt" "ff" "ss" "fs" "sf" "tt" "ff" "ss" "fs" "sf"

mappingList[as.numeric(factor(df2$A))]
#[1] "tt" "ff" "ss" "fs" "sf" "tt" "ff" "ss" "fs" "sf"
```