# Sqlite join columns on mapping of values

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, join

I want to be able to join two tables, where there is a mapping between the column values, rather than their values matching.

So rather than:

```
 A|m | f   B|m | f  
  a1  1     b1  1  
  a2  2     b2  3  
  a3  3     b3  5
```

> ```
>   SELECT a1, a2, b1, b2  
>     FROM A  
>     INNER JOIN B on B.f = A.f
> ```

giving:

```
 |m| A.f   B.f |m|   
  a1  1     1   b1  
  a3  3     3   b2
```

Given then mapping (1->a)(2->b)(3->c)

```
 A|m | f   B|m | f  
   a1  1     b1  a  
   a2  2     b2  b   
   a3  3     b3  c
```

to give when joined on f:

```
 |m| A.f   B.f |m|    
  a1  1     a   b1  
  a3  3     c   b2
```

The question below seems to be trying something similar, but they seem to want to change the column values, I just want the mappng to be part of the query, I don't want to change the column values thenselves. Besides it is in R and I'm working in Python.

[Mapping column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603086/mapping-column-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a temporary table of mappings `AB`:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE AB (a TEXT, b TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(a, b));
```

Then insert mappings,

```sql
INSERT INTO temp.AB VALUES (1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c");
```

or [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.executemany) with params.

Then select using intermediary table.

```sql
SELECT A.m AS Am, A.f AS Af, B.f AS Bf, B.m AS Bm
FROM A
LEFT JOIN temp.AB ON A.f=AB.a
LEFT JOIN B ON B.f=AB.b;
```

---

If you don't want to create an intermediary table, another solution would be building the query yourself.

```py
mappings = ((1,'a'), (3,'c'))
sql = 'SELECT A.m AS Am, A.f AS Af, B.f AS Bf, B.m AS Bm FROM A, B WHERE ' \
  + ' OR '.join(['(A.f=? AND B.f=?)'] * len(mappings))
c.execute(sql, [i for m in mappings for i in m])
```